# Wrap class list with media queries and suffix in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking for a way to generate responsive utility classes in SASS. I had this CSS

```
.text-left { text-align: left; }
.text-right { text-align: right; }

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .text-left-sm { text-align: left; }
  .text-right-sm { text-align: right; }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .text-left-md { text-align: left; }
  .text-right-md { text-align: right; }
}
```

and I would like to add some more, but I don't want to repeat myself. It would be best if SASS could generate all those responsive (media query) variants for me. So far I was able to write a mixin that I could call with suffix param and get what I want

```
@mixin textalign($suffix: "") {
  .text-left#{$suffix} { text-align: left; }
  .text-right#{$suffix} { text-align: right; }
}

@include textalign();

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  @include textalign("-sm");
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  @include textalign("-lg");
}
```

but I would like to go one step further and be able to do something like this

```
/* Unfortunatelly this doesn't work */
@include generate-responsive() {
  .text-left { text-align: left; }
  .text-right { text-align: right; }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this? Having a general purpose mixin that I can use to generate all kind of utility classes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can accomplish your goal when nesting your selector in the `@include`, but you can do it when nesting the `@include` inside the selector.

**SCSS input:**

```
@mixin generate-responsive() {
  // Create a list of sizes and widths
  $sizes: (
    sm: "480px",
    md: "600px",
    lg: "800px"
  );

  // Base style, without a suffix
  @content;

  // Responsive styles
  // Loop over each size
  @each $suffix, $width in $sizes {
    @media (min-width: $width) {
      &-#{$suffix} { @content; }
    }
  }
}

.text-left {
  @include generate-responsive() {
    text-align: left;
  }
}

// You'll have to include the mixin for every class
.text-right {
  @include generate-responsive() {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .text-left-sm {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .text-left-md {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .text-left-lg {
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
// Etc...
```

Comment: It looks interesting, but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. I need to be able to specify multiple selectors that must be suffixed. I've edited a question to make it more clear.

Comment: Use comma I suppose

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to loop through the contents (`@content`) inside a mixin, so I think you'll have to include `generate-responsive` for every different class.